# Diagrams boundingRect including the lines' width

Tags: haskell, graphics, haskell-diagrams

Is there an equivalent to the [boundingRect](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/Diagrams-TwoD-Combinators.html#v:boundingRect) function which includes the diagram's lines width(*), so that each line, however thick it is, is entirely contained within the bounding rectangle? (the `boundingRect` function "ignores" their thickness and parts of the lines stay outside the bounding rectangle).

(*) My question is for lines with width expressed in local units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this automatically yet. The easiest way would be to [`frame`](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/Diagrams-Combinators.html#v:frame) the diagram before finding the `boundingRect`. Since you're using the local units you just need to `frame` half the local width used in the diagram (add half of the line width used for the bounding rectangle if that has a line too).

Here's a simple example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Diagrams.Prelude
import Diagrams.Backend.Rasterific.CmdLine

main :: IO ()
main = mainWith $ frame 1 rects

rects :: Diagram B
rects = hsep 1 $ map (dia <>) [br1, br2, br3]
  where
    br1 = boundingRect dia # lwL 0.2 # lc red
    br2 = boundingRect (frame 0.1 dia) # fc dodgerblue # lw none
    br3 = boundingRect (frame 0.2 dia) # lwL 0.2 # lc red

dia :: Diagram B
dia = circle 3 # fc orange # lwL 0.2
```

[image: bounding rectangles]

A more general solution would be to draw the offset curves of each path using the local line width in the `Diagram` and find the bounding box of that. [`Diagrams.TwoD.Offset`](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/Diagrams-TwoD-Offset.html) can almost do this but I don't think it works for all cases.

Comment: Unfortunately the paths I'm working with are continuous, but not "smooth" (they have "spikes") and "framing" them as suggested can lead to mixed results. But I agree that it seems the best solution currently. Diagrams.TwoD.Offset offsetTrails functions would be better but I had problem with them.